# Wordpress Admin Section users.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Within **Wordpress** in the users section I would like to add a new row which will data pulled in from the **Register Plus** plugin.

Where would I need to create a new row?

Example:

```
Username    Name        E-mail              Role                **Website**          Posts
Admin        Admin      admin@admin.com     Administrator       google.com       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

It's in wp-admin/includes/template.php

Comment: Editing the core files is bad - when you upgrade wordpress, this will be overwritten. I believe there are ways of adding table columns to the admin using a plugin (or functions.php in your theme folder) - this method is more future-proof